# else condition get's somehow bypassed when the user input has a value

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, while-loop, cout

So i'm trying to make a programm that repeatedly asks the user to guess a number. He then loses (or the programm quits) if one of these conditions are true:

- user uses the number 5
- user uses a number bigger then 10
- user uses a number that is equal to the number of the guessed times he has already guessed
- user has only 10 tries

Here is the problem, if I input the number 5 as my first guess the else function works and cout outputs the strings **but** if I first guess something else and then use the number 5 for some reason the program just quits without outputting the string in the last else block.

Here is were I would love to see some feedback on what I need to change so that I can input multiple user input and **then** still us the number 5 to get the cout strings in the else function. Thank you in advance :)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {

   int input = 0;
   short counter = 0;

   cout << "Hello fellow PC-User why don't you guess a number that is between 1-10 ?" << endl;
   cout << "Come on give it a try!\nOnly two conditions (maybe three) don't use the Number 5 and only Numbers 1-10!\nNow let's go!!!" << endl;
   cin >> input;



   if(input != 5 && input < 10){

      while(input != 5 && input < 10) {
         ++counter;
         cout << "Nice you guessed " << counter << flush;
         if (input > 1){
            cout <<" times!" << flush;
         } else{
            cout << " time!" << flush;
         }
         cout << "\nNow go at it again just don't used the number the times u tried bro!" << endl;
         cin >> input;
         if(counter == 10){
            cout << "Damn that motivation doe...well what can I say\n I give up \n U win." << endl;
            return 0;
         }       else if(counter == input){
            cout << "Don't do it..." << endl;
            return 0;
         }
      }
   } else {
      cout << "Yo! You weren't supposed to use that number!\nNow u looooose" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` part of the block doesn't get invoked in the `while` loop inside the `if` block.

If your first input is correct, i.e. the conditional in

```
if(input != 5 && input < 10){
```

evaluates to `true`, the `else` part will never get executed. You will need to reorganize the `if` block and the `while` loop a bit differently if you want the `else` block to be executed no matter when the conditional of the `if` statement evaluates to false.

```
// Simple conditional.
// Loop forever until a break statement in the loop breaks the loop.
while(true ) {

   if(input != 5 && input < 10){

      ++counter;
      cout << "Nice you guessed " << counter << flush;
      if (input > 1){
         cout <<" times!" << flush;
      } else{
         cout << " time!" << flush;
      }
      cout << "\nNow go at it again just don't used the number the times u tried bro!" << endl;
      cin >> input;
      if(counter == 10){
         cout << "Damn that motivation doe...well what can I say\n I give up \n U win." << endl;
         return 0;
      }       else if(counter == input){
         cout << "Don't do it..." << endl;
         return 0;
      }
   } else {
      cout << "Yo! You weren't supposed to use that number!\nNow u looooose" << endl;

      // Provide a way to break out of the while loop.
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

outer if condition is really not needed because it will execute only first time. Just move that if-else part after while loop and see what happens. Actually that if condition is not needed at all, since you will exit while loop only if input == 5 or input > 10. And you need to take care of negative numbers also.

Comment: Didn't think about negative numbers next thins i'm gonna try and sort out. Thanks!